# Why does createProcessingInstruction in MSXML generate incomplete output?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, msxml

The following VBA code generates `<?xml version="1.0"?>` as output.

```
Dim XML As New DomDocument 
Dim pi As IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction

'.... some code that sets the root element of the document

Set pi = XML.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
        XML.insertBefore pi, XML.documentElement
```

Why is the `encoding="UTF-8"` left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is the default encoding anyway. What you've specified is redundant, so the serializer likely omits it. The `version` field is not an optional field, though. If the file has an XML declaration at all, [the declaration must include the `version` field](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd).

Comment: version is also default. still it's in the output.

Comment: Um, thanks for accepting my answer, but I'm inclined to think Bobince's is the better one. Apparently, despite looking just like a processing instruction, <?xml isn't one, so don't use createProcessingInstruction for that.

Answer (score 10):

<?xml?> is *not* a Processing Instruction. The <?xml?> construct is called the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) and obeys different rules to a real Processing Instruction. Creating a PI with name ‘xml’ is not well-formed; names beginning with ‘xml’ are [reserved](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-pi).

To change the format of the prolog you need to [configure an XMLWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759110(VS.85).aspx), setting ‘version’, ‘encoding’ or simply ‘omitXMLDeclaration’ to remove it altogether, which is perfectly fine since 1.0 and UTF-8 are the default values.

Comment: +1 Verified that XMLWriter with SAX Content Handler produces the output that OP expects. `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`